# RXJava2 How to combine 2 observables in one

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

I have two api that returns objects:

```
public class Enemy{

private String name;
private int id;
private EnemyCharacteristics enemyCharacteristics;
```

+getters and setters

```
public class EnemyCharacteristics {

private ArrayList<Abilities> abilities;
private ArrayList<Stats> stats;
```

+getters and setters

I have Retrofit interface:

```
public interface ApiService{
@GET("enemy")
Observable<EnemyResult> getEnemyResult(@Query("limit") int limit, @Query("offset") int offset);

@GET("enemy/{name}")
Observable<EnemyCharacteristics> getEnemyCharacteristics(@Path("name") String name);
```

I send request getEnemyResult(), it returns:

```
public class EnemyResult{

private ArrayList<Enemy> results;

public ArrayList<Enemy> getResults() {
    return results;
}

public void setResults(ArrayList<Enemy> results) {
    this.results = results;
}
```

}

Next, I need to send for each Enemy request getEnemyCharacteristics() and call Enemy.setEnemyCharacteristics() with result.

How should I combine two this requests with RXJava2 to return Enemy objects with EnemyCharacteristics as part of Enemy?

Comment: as getEnemyCharacteristics returns more than one EnemyCharacteristics (`Observable<EnemyCharacteristics>`), which one should be used to call `Enemy.setEnemyCharacteristics()`? just the first one?

Comment: Second api request have argument - Enemy.name. Api returns only one EnemyCharacteristics for this name of Enemy:
apiService.getEnemyCharacteristics(name);

Answer (score 1):

```
getEnemyResult(..)
    .flatMapIterable(result -> result.getResults())
    .flatMap(enemy -> 
        getEnemyCharacteristics(enemy.name)
            .firstElement()
            .flatMap(characteristics -> {
                enemy.setEnemyCharacteristics(characteristics);
                return Maybe.just(enemy);
            })
    )
```